# Is there a way to set an MP3 file as a ringtone on Android using Adobe AIR?

Tags: android, air, ringtone

I'm working on an Adobe AIR application for Android.  Is it possible to set an MP3 file (or any music file) as a ringtone on the device using AIR?  If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with built-in AIR APIs. However, now that AIR 3 is out, you can access almost all Android features by creating a native extension.